# unlink function not working for image in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, unlink

I have a problem in image unlink in Internet Explorer, but it works in Mozilla.

I have used php code:

```
<?php

unlink("./product_photos/".$name);


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is not affected by *browser quirks*.

If `unlink()` is failing, it probably has to do with your PHP. Does the file path point to a file? What does `var_dump(file_exists("./product_photos/".$name));` say before deleting it? If it isn't `(bool) true`, there is your problem :)

Be also sure that`$name` is sanitized if it is from the user, otherwise I may enter `../../../your-site/index.php` (a directory traversal attack).

Comment: But the exists may be path is wrong, site's url hasn't www, is it any problem